# how to select HTML DOM first character using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

how to select first characterin html DOM.  I tried  `$('#pcode')[0];` to get first character but its not giving first value when I am trying to print it its printing `[object HTMLInputElement]`
how to select HTML DOM first character using jquery

Comment: Please post your HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just pulling the object with

```
$('#pcode')[0];
```

You need to pull the value associated with the object

```
$('#pcode').val()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have some text in an element with the id "pcode" and you want the first character. If that is so then you want to do the following:

```
$("#pcode").val().charAt(0);
```

Comment: @Krishna..yeah thnq :)